# Windows Storage Spaces broken after Windows Update

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-update, storage-spaces

I've got a Simple (no resiliency) storage space configured on Windows 10, it's just some cheap low capacity sata SSD's striped together to make a fast game drive. Fortunately just steam games installed on it.

I shutdown my computer last night and installed 3 Windows updates, KB5028166, KB5028853 and Servicing Stack 10.0.19041.3205, when I turned it on again this evening, my storage space wasn't present in file explorer, I've opened manage storage spaces and it shows a low capacity warning, but all 4 drives are still present with OK next to them.
I pressed change settings and then "Bring Online", this showed the volume in file explorer and I can see the file structure, but going more than a few folders deep, I get an access denied error. I've created a text document on the volume and saved it and and re-opened it without corruption.

I've seen a similar question on here (although they could still access their data), and run the powershell command that solved for them (Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter S -Verbose), but this didn't work.

Is there any way I can save this pool? I'm sure all the data is fine and storage spaces as well as Crystal Disk Info shows all the SSD's as healthy. Worst case I'll re-download my games, but it will likely take days so would rather have a crack at fixing if possible.

[Screenshot of Storage Spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3019t.png)

Update: Upon a reboot the storage space always goes offline, checking in disk management before onlining the pool, I get the error "Offline due to critical write failures". Storage spaces doesn't give any errors which I think is strange. But I must have a physical failure. Time to investigate further, but the data is gone anyway.

Comment: If you click on “View Settings” what happens?

Comment: @Ramhound Where do you mean? I can't see a "View Settings" on Storage Spaces, unless I'm being blind.

Comment: Sorry, autocorrect, “View Files”.

Comment: @Ramhound Just opens the drive in file explorer, same symptoms as in the OP.